# Add Tensorflow package/library to Kernel of Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have already installed Anaconda and using jupyter notebook. Looking to add a Tensorflow.

I installed the full packages, activated and also used pip command

Finally, the issue is that: the Python versions, Tensorflow is on drive E! but the base is on drive C:

I change the directory to E, but still don't have TF as a new kernel in jupyter notebook.

What solutions do you suggest?

Re, Al

Comment: So installing tensorflow through Anaconda should give you everything you need inside of that environment already, unless you're playing around with cuda drivers and trying to get that working for GPU-based deep learning.Can you clarify what you mean when you say `Finally, the issue is that: the Python versions, Tensorflow is on drive E! but the base is on drive C`?

Comment: Actually, the env file is available. But the directory I've created is not available in Jupyter Kernel. I have doubts about the path, coz <base> located at drive C:, while installation of TensorFlow went to drive E! I had a folder called Anaconda in E as well. So, I'm wondering this mismatch between directories may create this issue.